# Adding XML piece to an existing XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, addition, transformation, mule

I am trying to add a piece of an XML to an input XML using XSLT. But the output is not coming as expected. Pelase help.

My input XML :

```
    <input  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd">
        <nodeA id="test">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeB id="test">
            <inodeBA> Sample </inodeBA>
            <inodeBB> Samples </inodeBB>
        </nodeB>
    </input>
```

Below is another XML piece which I am passing as a parameter to me XSLT. 
This piece is to be added to the input XML:

```
    <ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
        <ns3:reply id="rep">
            <ns3:zip>55555</ns3:zip>
            <ns3:place>SampleLoc</ns3:place>
        </ns3:reply>
    </ns3:output>
```

Below is my Expected Output:

```
    <input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd">
        <nodeA id="test">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeB id="test">
            <inodeBA> Sample </inodeBA>
            <inodeBB> Samples </inodeBB>
        </nodeB>

        <ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
            <ns3:reply id="rep">
                <ns3:zip>55555</ns3:zip>
                <ns3:place>SampleLoc</ns3:place>
            </ns3:reply>
        </ns3:output>

    </input>
```

Below is the XSL I am using for this task:

In the below XSLT the param "outParam" holds the xml piece which I am trying to add to me input.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org"
        exclude-result-prefixes="soap xsl">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:param name="outParam"></xsl:param>

        <xsl:template match="input">
            <input>
                <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="./@*" />
                <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="node() | @*" />
            </input>
            <xsl:copy >
                <xsl:value-of select="$outParam" disable-output-escaping="yes" ></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the output I am getting. This is not matching my expected output.

```
    <input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org"  
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd" >
        <nodeA id="test">
            <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
            <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeB id="test">
            <inodeBA> Sample </inodeBA>
            <inodeBB> Samples </inodeBB>
        </nodeB>
    </input>
    <input xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   
        <ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
            <ns3:reply id="rep">
                <ns3:zip>55555</ns3:zip>
                <ns3:place>SampleLoc</ns3:place>
            </ns3:reply>
        </ns3:output>
    </input>
```

Please help. I have tried many combinations but no luck. :(

Note: I am performing this transformation using the Mule XSLT Transformer which transforms payload XML based on the XSLT provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameter is a node or sequence of nodes all you need is

```
<xsl:template match="input">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@* , node(), $outParam"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If the parameter passed in is a string with XML markup then you need

```
<xsl:template match="input">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*, node()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$outParam" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but there is a problem with this. the output looks as below <input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd" > <nodeA id="test"> ...... &lt;ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org"&gt; &lt;ns3:reply id="rep"$gt; &lt;ns3:zip&gt;55555&lt;/ns3:zip&gt;  .....  &lt;/ns3:output&gt; </input>

Comment: the output is being escaped. byt converting the < and >  to &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Well I assumed the parameter value passed in is a node or a sequence of nodes. It seems to be a string with XML markup. I am not familiar with Mule so I can't tell whether it is possible to change the parameter type. But I will edit my post to show how to deal with a string parameter.

Comment: Hurray.........   I got it with the second option you have given....  Thank you so much for your help..... :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

If EXSLT is an option, add `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` and try

```
    <xsl:template match="input">
        <input>
            <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="./@*" />
            <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="node() | @*" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($outParam)/*" />
        </input>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried this and the output is show as below            <input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org"  
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nbA2.8.90.xsd" >
   <nodeA id="test">
    <inodeAA> Sample </inodeAA>
    <inodeAB> Samples </inodeAB>
   </nodeA>
   .........
   <input xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ns3:output xmlns:ns3="http://mysample.org">
    <ns3:reply id="rep">
     ............
    </ns3:reply>
   </ns3:output>
   </input>   
  </input>

Comment: This is still not giving me the desired output.

Comment: You could try change `<xsl:value-of select="$outParam" disable-output-escaping="yes" ></xsl:value-of>` to `<xsl:value-of select="$outParam/*" disable-output-escaping="yes" ></xsl:value-of>`

Comment: Tried it.. but got an exception.....           Exception stack is:
1. Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError)
  net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression:791 (null)
2. Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer:184 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)

Comment: OK, I've changed it to the way I would use it, using EXSLT's `node-set()` to properly transform the parameter to a nodeset. This should work either out of the box or with `exsl:node-set($outParam)/*`.

Comment: I got it with the second option given in the above answer....    Thank you very much for you help......   So nice of you...